# How to add custom class to a cell in the column definition TankStank v8

Tags: solid-js, tanstack-table

I'm trying to add a class from the Column definition to the  element. Like the following

```
const defaultColumns: ColumnDef<Person>[] = [
{
    accessorKey: 'firstName',
    cell: info => info.getValue(),
    footer: info => info.column.id,
    myCustomClassList: ["d-flex"] // custom class only to this column
}]


<For each={row.getVisibleCells()}>
    {cell => (
        <td class={...cell.myCustomClass()}> // Add class here
            {flexRender(
                cell.column.columnDef.cell,
                cell.getContext()
            )}
        </td>
    )}
</For>
```

I was browsing and I found [this issue](https://github.com/TanStack/table/issues/1640) that explains that previewsly, a className property could be provided but now in version 7 its done through custom props using `cell.getCellProps`, and it redirects me to [this issue](https://github.com/TanStack/table/issues/1612) that has [this working example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/tannerlinsleyreact-table-basic-evgp3?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js). But it did not work in version 8.

Reading the [documentation for migration to v8](https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/guide/migrating#migrate-table-markup), it says that this option was deprecated, but it does not give any replacement. It uses `flexRender` but only inside the  element, so it does not expose any properties to the td but the id.
[image]

I think its a pretty common thing to need, but I could not find anything in the docs or in the examples (maybe did not look hard enough) but any help is really appreciated

Note: I know that I can change my render funcion and start the rendering outside the  like the following:

```
const defaultColumns: ColumnDef<Person>[] = [
{
    accessorKey: 'firstName',
    cell: info => <td class="d-flex">{info.getValue()}<td>,
    footer: info => info.column.id
}]

<For each={row.getVisibleCells()}>
    {cell => (
        {flexRender(
                cell.column.columnDef.cell,
                cell.getContext()
        )}
    )}
</For>
```

But this would require me to manually add the  element to each column even when 90% of the time I dont need to add a custom class. I think I am missing something from the v8 docuentantion hopefully simple. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [this discussion](https://github.com/TanStack/table/discussions/5319) and with a little bit of digging to keep the type system happy this is the official way to add custom classes or any other custom information you need for you columns

#### 1. If you are using Typescript: add an [extension to the ColumnMeta interface](https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/api/core/column-def#meta)

*(if you are not using typescript you can skip to step 2)*

```
declare module '@tanstack/solid-table' {
    interface ColumnMeta<TData extends RowData, TValue> {
        myCustomClass: string
    }
}
```

#### 2. Add your propery to the desired column

```
const defaultColumns: ColumnDef<Person>[] = [
{
    accessorKey: 'firstName',
    cell: info => info.getValue(),
    footer: info => info.column.id,
    // add meta property
    meta: {
        myCustomClass: "bg-red-500",// declare the property here
    }
},
...
```

#### 3. Use the property on your table render

```
<For each={row.getVisibleCells()}>
    {cell => (
        <td class={cell.column.columnDef.meta?.class ?? ""}>
            {flexRender(cell.column.columnDef.cell, cell.getContext())}
        </td>
    )}
</For>
```